# Rename files by type in a shell script using file command

Tags: bash, shell, file, rename

I try rename some files without any extensions with a shell script.

For example i have this result for now :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/volume1 $ sh test.sh
01  test2.sh  test3.sh  test.sh
/home/pi/volume1/test2.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/home/pi/volume1/01/02/**000022223333434444440000**: **gzip** compressed data, last modified: Mon Oct  9 04:17:03 2017, from Unix
```

And i would like to rename 000022223333434444440000 file in 000022223333434444440000.gzip file

and the same for PDF or ODT files will be perfect.

My script is for gzip files  :

```
#!/bin/bash

PWD=/home/pi/volume1

ls $PWD

var=$(find $PWD -type f -exec file {} \; | grep "gzip")
```

Can you please help me to learn how to select the gzip to rename the original file with the right extension please ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to rename the files with a dot grip extension? Because the convention is that the gzip file has a gz extension. Just a quick clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a specific extension and rename in this way:

```
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    mv "$REPLY" "${REPLY%.*}.gz"
done < <(find /home/pi/volume1 -iname "*.gzip" -print0)
```